# Best practice to return a Result<_, impl Error> and not a Result<_, &str> in Rust?

Tags: rust

Is it ok practice to have this style `Result`?

```rust
fn a() -> Result<u32, &'static str>
```

And then what is the purpose of the Error trait? https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html

Is an impl Error Result better practice?

```rust
impl Error for MyError {..... }
fn a() -> Result<u32, MyError>
```

Comment: I don't know why you think that `&str` as the error type is good design. Have you read [the relevant section of the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html)? See also the [C-GOOD-ERR](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/api-guidelines/interoperability.html#c-good-err) API guideline. The third question might be too subjective. (even when disregarding the syntax error on that 2nd line of code)

Comment: What do you want, to understand the differences between these things? Or just for someone to tell you it's OK to use `Result<_, &'static str>` everywhere? Error handling can be a book in itself (not just in Rust). I don't think this question is constructively answerable.

Comment: I think I got my answer already. That there is no clear answer here. And I am already mostly aware of the tradeoffs between the two methods. Sync error was intentional pseudocode. Will update the question to make that clear

Answer (score 11):

In short: No, it's not okay. String as error throws away information about details and cause, making errors useless for callers as they won't be able to inspect and possibly recover from it.

In case you just need to fill Error parameter with something, create a unit struct. It's not much useful, but it's also not as volative as string. And you can easily distinguish `foo::SomeError` from `bar::SomeError`.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct SomeError; // No fields.
```

In case you can enumerate error variants, use `enum`.
It is also sometimes useful to "include" other errors into it.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum PasswordError {
    Empty,
    ToShort,
    NoDigits,
    NoLetters,
    NoSpecials
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum ConfigLoadError {
   InvalidValues,
   DeserializationError(serde::de::Error),
   IoError(std::io::Error),
}
```

Nobody stops you from using `struct`s.
They're particularly useful when you intentionaly want to hide some information from caller (In contrast to `enum`s whose variants always have public visibility). E.g. caller has nothing to do with error message, but can use `kind` to handle it:

```rust
pub enum RegistrationErrorKind {
    InvalidName { wrong_char_idx: usize },
    NonUniqueName,
    WeakPassword,
    DatabaseError(db::Error),
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct RegistrationError {
    message: String, // Private field
    pub kind: RegistrationErrorKind, // Public field
}
```

**impl Error** - existential type - makes no sense here. You can't return different error types with it in error place, if this was your intent. And opaque errors are not much useful, just like strings.

`std::error::Error` trait ensures that your `SomeError` type has implementation for `std::fmt::{Display, Debug}` (For displaying error to user and developer, correspondingly) and provides some useful methods like `source` (This returns the cause of this error); `is`, `downcast`, `downcast_ref`, `downcast_mut`. Last 4 are for error type erasure.

**Error type erasure**

Error type erasure has it's tradeoffs, but it's also worth mentioning.

It's also especially useful when writing somewht high-level application code. But in case of libraries you should think twice before deciding to use this approach, because it will make your library unusable with 'no_std'.

Say you have some function with non-trivial logic that can return values of some error types, not exactly one. In this case you can use (But don't abuse) error type erasure:

```
use std::error::Error;
use std::fmt;
use std::fs;
use std::io::Error as IoError;
use std::net::AddrParseError;
use std::net::Ipv4Addr
use std::path::Path;

// Error for case where file contains '127.0.0.1'
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct AddressIsLocalhostError;

// Display implementation is required for std::error::Error.
impl fmt::Display for AddressIsLocalhostError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "Address is localhost")
    }
}

impl Error for AddresIsLocalhostError {} // Defaults are okay here.

// Now we have a function that takes a path and returns 
// non-localhost Ipv4Addr on success.
// On fail it can return either of IoError, AddrParseError or AddressIsLocalhostError.
fn non_localhost_ipv4_from_file(path: &Path) -> Result<Ipv4Addr, Box<dyn Error + 'static>> {
    // Opening and reading file may cause IoError.
    // ? operator will automatically convert it to Box<dyn Error + 'static>. 
    // (via From trait implementation)
    // This way concrete type of error is "erased": we don't know what's
    // in a box, in fact it's kind of black box now, but we still can call
    // methods that Error trait provides.
    let content = fs::read_to_string(path)?;

    // Parsing Ipv4Addr from string [slice] 
    // may cause another error: AddressParseError.
    // And ? will convert it to to the same type: Box<dyn Error + 'static>
    let addr: Ipv4Addr = content.parse()?;

    if addr == Ipv4Add::new(127, 0, 0, 1) {
        // Here we perform manual conversion 
        // from AddressIsLocalhostError 
        // to Box<dyn Error + 'static> and return error.
        return Err(AddressIsLocalhostError.into());
    }

    // Everyhing is okay, returning addr.
    Ok(Ipv4Addr)
}


fn main() {
    // Let's try to use our function.
    let maybe_address = non_localhost_ipv4_from_file(
        "sure_it_contains_localhost.conf"
    );

    // Let's see what kind of magic Error trait provides!
    match maybe_address {
        // Print address on success.
        Ok(addr) => println!("File was containing address: {}", addr),
        Err(err) => {
            // We sure can just print this error with.
            // println!("{}", err.as_ref());
            // Because Error implementation implies Display implementation.
            // But let's imagine we want to inspect error.

            // Here deref coercion implicitly converts
            // `&Box<dyn Error>` to `&dyn Error`.
            // And downcast_ref tries to convert this &dyn Error
            // back to &IoError, returning either
            // Some(&IoError) or none
            if Some(err) = err.downcast_ref::<IoError>() {
                println!("Unfortunately, IO error occured: {}", err)
            }

            // There's also downcast_mut, which does the same, but gives us
            // mutable reference.
            if Some(mut err) = err.downcast_mut::<AddressParseError>() {
                // Here we can mutate err. But we'll only print it.
                println!(
                    "Unfortunately, what file was cantaining, \
                     was not in fact an ipv4 address: {}",
                    err
                );
            }

            // Finally there's 'is' and 'downcast'.
            // 'is' comapres "erased" type with some concrete type.
            if err.is::<AddressIsLocalhostError>() {
               // 'downcast' tries to convert Box<dyn Error + 'static>
               // to box with value of some concrete type.
               // Here - to Box<AddressIsLocalhostError>.
               let err: Box<AddressIsLocalhostError> = 
                   Error::downcast(err).unwrap();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

To summarize: errors should (I'd say - must) provide useful information to caller, besides ability to just display them, thus they should not be strings. And errors must implement Error at least to preserve more-less consistent error handling experience across all crates. All the rest depends on situation.

Caio alredy mentioned The Rust Book.

But these links might be also useful:

[std::any module level API documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/index.html)

[std::error::Error API documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html)

Answer (score 4):

For simple use-cases, a opaque error type like `Result<u32, &'static str>` or `Result<u32, String>` is enough but for more complex libraries, it is useful and even encouraged to create your own error type like a `struct MyError` or `enum AnotherLibError`, which helps you to define better your intentions. You may also want to read the [`Error Handling`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/error.html) chapter of the `Rust by Example` book.

The `Error` trait, as being part of `std`, helps developers in a generic and centralized manner to define their own error types to describe what happened and the possible root causes (backtrace). It is currently somewhat limited but there are plans to help to [improve its usability](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2504-fix-error.md).

When you use `impl Error`, you are telling the compiler that you don't care about the type being returned, as long it implements the `Error` trait. This approach is useful when the error type is too complex or when you want to generalize over the return type. E.g.:

```
fn example() -> Result<Duration, impl Error> {
    let sys_time = SystemTime::now();
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
    let new_sys_time = SystemTime::now();
    sys_time.duration_since(new_sys_time)
}
```

The method `duration_since` returns a `Result<Duration, SystemTimeError>` type but in the above method signature, you can see that for the [`Err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/core/result/enum.Result.html#variant.Err) part of the Result, it is returning anything that implements the `Error` trait.

Summarizing everything, if you read the Rust book and know what you are doing, you can choose the approach that best fits your needs. Otherwise, it is best to define your own types for your errors or use some third-party utilities like the `error-chain` or `failure` crates.