# Should I abstract error types in my Rust API?

Tags: error-handling, rust, idioms

I'm writing a Rust tool which should help me storing my photos in an orderly way. I'm writing the tool as if it was a really important project. I'm at the point where I need to conceptualize how I handle errors.

The underlying library works a lot with the file system, so there are a lot of IO errors that can occur. I want my photos to be stored in a specific file structure (a photo is named like this `{number}_{event}.{extension}` for example). If a library user violates this structure there are library-specific errors that can occur as well.

I've thought about two different approaches:

1. I create my own error type for the library-specific errors. My public functions will return something like `Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>`.
2. I create my own error type for the library-specific errors and also use it as a wrapper around the IO errors. My public functions will return something like `Result<(), LibraryError>`

The difference I can think of is that 1 is less work for the dev but also less convenient for the user; 2 is more work for the dev but also more convenient for the user, but maybe I'm wrong.

Is one alternative clearly better? Are there different approaches to my problem which I'm missing? Am I even on the right path?

Or to ask it in Rust terms: What is the idiomatic way of doing this?

Comment: Yes, this is opinion-based. Yes, you should abstract them. You should use my [SNAFU](https://docs.rs/snafu/) library to reduce the work required to create good errors.

Comment: Your question may be answered by the answers of [How do you define custom `Error` types in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42584368/155423); [Rust proper error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48430836/155423); [Error handling best-practices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28911833/155423); [Best practice to return a Result<_, impl Error> and not a Result<_, &str> in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54159232/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Because this question in its current form appears off-topic, you may wish to look at other resources. More open-ended questions and discussions are welcome on [the Rust users forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/), [the Rust subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/), [the Rust Discord server](https://www.rust-lang.org/community), or [the Stack Overflow Rust chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62927/rust).

Comment: Thank you, @Shepmaster. Your answer at [How do you define custom `Error` types in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42584368/how-do-you-define-custom-error-types-in-rust) is very informative. You can therefore mark it as answered (or tell me how to do it myself).

Comment: You should be able to click "close" under your post and mark it a duplicate of whatever other post is most applicable. See [How do I close my own question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37752/281829) as well.

Comment: The answer of that question sais I need 250 rep which I haven't.